# How do I removed a particular item from a embedded array in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

given sample data like:

```
{
   'id': 1,
   'things': [{'name': 'a'},{'name': 'b'},{'name': 'c'}]
}
```

how do I update the document removing the array item with name of 'b' from the embedded array?

```
r.table('test')
.get(1)
.update({things: r.row('things')????});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `update` command along with `filter` to filter the elements in an array and pass to along to `update`.

```
r.table('30848200').get(1).update(function (row)  {
  return {
    'things': row('things')
      .filter(function (item) { return item('name').ne('b') })
  }
})
```

Basically, you'll be overwriting `things` with the filtered array.